# Java: Exception testing with Junit 3

Tags: java, exception, junit, error-handling, junit3

I would like to write a test for `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Keep in mind that we are supposed to use JUnit 3.

**My code:**

```
public boolean ajouter(int indice, T element) {
    if (indice < 0 || indice > (maListe.size() - 1)) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    } else if (element != null && !maListe.contains(element)) {
        maListe.set(indice, element);
        return true;
    }
}
```

After some research, I found that you can do this with JUnit 4 using `@Test(expected = IndexOutOfBoundsException.class)` but no where did I find how to do this in JUnit 3.

How can I test this using JUnit 3?

Answer (score 36):

Testing exceptions in JUnit 3 uses this pattern:

```
try {
     ... code that should throw an exception ...

     fail( "Missing exception" );
} catch( IndexOutOfBoundsException e ) {
     assertEquals( "Expected message", e.getMessage() ); // Optionally make sure you get the correct message, too
}
```

The `fail()` makes sure you get an error if the code doesn't throw an exception.

I use this pattern in JUnit 4 as well since I usually want to make sure the correct values are visible in the exception message and `@Test` can't do that.

Comment: In JUnit 4, you can set an expected exception in @Test but you can also use [ExpectedExceptions](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html) which are more flexible and allow to check the message.

Comment: Ah, didn't know about this rule. It was added with JUnit 4.7.

Answer (score 15):

Basically, you need to call your method and fail if it *doesn't* throw the right exception - or if it throws anything else:

```
try {
  subject.ajouter(10, "foo");
  fail("Expected exception");
} catch (IndexOutOfBoundException expect) {
  // We should get here. You may assert things about the exception, if you want.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution is to add a try catch to the unittest and let the test fail when the exception isn't thrown

```
public void testAjouterFail() {
  try {
    ajouter(-1,null);
    JUnit.fail();
  catch (IndexOutOfBoundException()) {
    //success
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One thing you can do is use a boolean to run the test to completion and then you can use assert to validate the exception was thrown:

```
boolean passed = false;
try
{
    //the line that throws exception
    //i.e. illegal argument exception
    //if user tries to set the property to null:
    myObject.setProperty(null);
}
catch (IllegalArgumentException iaex)
{
    passed = true;
}
assertTrue("The blah blah blah exception was not thrown as expected"
              , passed);
```

By using this test, your test will never fail to execute and you can validate that a specific exception type is thrown.

Answer (score 3):

Extending @Aaron's solution with some (static import) syntactic sugar allows writing:

```
    expected(MyException.class,
        new Testable() {
            public void test() {
            ... do thing that's supposed to throw MyException ...
            }
        });
```

`Testable` is like a Runnable which uses test() signature throwing Throwable.

```
public class TestHelper {
    public static void expected(Class<? extends Throwable> expectedClass, Testable testable) {
        try {
            testable.test();
            fail("Expected "+ expectedClass.getCanonicalName() +" not thrown.");
        } catch (Throwable actual) {
            assertEquals("Expected "+ expectedClass.getCanonicalName() +" to be thrown.", expectedClass, actual.getClass());
        }
    }

    interface Testable {
        public void test() throws Throwable;
    }
}
```

You could add checking of the exception message as required.

Answer (score 2):

In your test method, call `ajouter()` inside a `try`..`catch` block, giving a value of `indice` that should cause the exception to be thrown, with

- a `catch` clause that catches `IndexOutOfBoundsException`: in that case return from your test method and thus indicate a pass.
- a second `catch` clause that catches `Throwable`: in that case declare a failure (call `fail()`), because the wrong kind of exception was thrown
- after the `try`..`catch` declare a failure (call `fail()`), because no exception was thrown.